# Air Travel In Mexico for US Citizens

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, mexico, passport-renewals

I'm flying out of Mexicali BC. Mexico in July.

The problem is I lost my US Passport. To fly in Mexico do I need a passport with a visa? I ask because since both my parents have dual citizenship, I didn't know if I would need my passport.

Second question: is it enough time if I order my passport within the next week since its a renewal? Will it take long to get to me? This way I can have time to get the visa to travel in Mexico????

Than you all whom is taking their time to give me some advice I've never traveled into Mexico before so I really want to go also trip is in July 2020 will that be enough time to get my new passport and visa to go to Mexico?

Comment: Do you have dual citizenship and a second passport? If so, which?

Comment: Have you reported your US passport as lost? https://www.usa.gov/passport-problems

Comment: If you applied for a new US passport now you would have it by July 2020.  You don't say where you are flying to - if it's an international flight from Mexicali you will need a passport.

Comment: If you also have Mexican citizenship, why aren't you planning to use your Mexican passport?

Comment: @Magones88 Your question needs more info, please see the comments above and [edit] your question to clarify your situation